# Replacing MATCH MySQL Function in a FilterExpression

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to develope a section of a software where it takes part objectDataSource.FilterExpression. When I build the filter I have this:

```
if (!txtBuscador.Text.Equals(String.Empty))
    {
        filtro += " AND MATCH(codigo_fichero, codigo_colectivo, codigo_ambito, codigo_area, titulo, resumen, palabras_clave, descriptores) AGAINST (\"" + txtBuscador.Text + "\" IN BOOLEAN MODE)";
    }
```

Everything goes well and when I debug step by step and I am at this point:

```
contador = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Compute("COUNT(nserie)", odsResultados.FilterExpression).ToString());
```

The application throws an EvaluateException because of the MATCH, so is there any way to change this and have the same functionallity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the value of `odsResultados.FilterExpression` exactly?

Comment: odsResultados is the name of the  ObjectDatasource which I use to bind it to a listview

Comment: No I mean, when you debug your code, what is the string value that contains?

Comment: I have this: MATCH(codigo_fichero, codigo_colectivo, codigo_ambito, codigo_area, titulo, resumen, palabras_clave, descriptores) AGAINST ("Real Patronato" IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Comment: I think this is not a valid [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MATCH doesn't work with FilterExpression, so I had to replace this with another expression, in my case with OR...

```
filtro += " AND codigo_fichero LIKE '%" + txtBuscador.Text + "%' OR codigo_colectivo LIKE '%" + txtBuscador.Text + "%' OR codigo_ambito LIKE '%" + txtBuscador.Text + "%' OR codigo_area LIKE '%" + txtBuscador.Text + "%' OR titulo LIKE '%" + txtBuscador.Text + "%' OR resumen LIKE '%" + txtBuscador.Text + "%'";
```